# Check if an object is valid?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I sign my URLs so they are only valid for a set period of time.

When the URLs are invalid, I get:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The     document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to check the object the URL is valid or not, if it's not valid I wish to redirect a user to a generic error page.

Comment: When you say "valid," what do you mean?  How does a signed url become something other than "valid?"  You presumably don't mean "expired," so... in what sense are your signed URLs not "valid?" Is your signing code broken? Are you signing urls to things that don't exist? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You can user the function `string file_get_contents(string $url)` to get the output of the URL, 
then check if the response is what you specified above (Keep in mind that the "This XML file does not have any style..." isn't a part of the respnse).

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    if (file_get_contents("http://example.com/foo/bar") === $errorResponse) {
        //There was an error
        header("Location: http://example.com/redirect/");
    }
?>
```

If the error message isn't always the same, you can use an XML parser to check if `<Error>` exists or just use regex.

Comment: Thanks, I wish to check this on quite large videos. Will file_get_contents download the entire video before checking? Is there a way around this?

Comment: If they are links to actual video file, then it will load the entire thing into RAM. 

You might be able to use curl and set a very short `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`, then, if it finished, parse the file and if it didn't, the file is probably very large and the request finished correctly

Comment: Couldn't you just dump the response code?  If it's anything other then HTTP 403, it's still good?

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: In order to get the status code, you first have to download the document. If there is no error, the huge video file will get loaded into ram, possibly crashing the app. And it would take forever